# Online java code evaluator cannot find my variables

Tags: java, class, variables

So I've been doing some online studying for Java (beginner) and I've been trying to make a class file for making a Rectangle. However, my online java evaluator states that it cannot find an instance variable.[This is the comment on it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KipAc.png) My first part of my code which states the variables looks like this:

```
public class Rectangle{

private static int height,width,MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT;
private String name;

public static void Rectangle(){

    String name = "default";
    MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
    MAX_WIDTH = 100;
    width = 10;
    height = 10;
}
```

I can't think of any other part of my code that would make it not visible to the evaluating software and I'm confident it's not a bug in the evaluating software. Also the variables have to be private for this assignment to give me the points.

Comment: You don't have **instance** variables `width` and `height`.

Comment: I recommend the [Oracle Tutorial on Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: why your height and width and constructor is `static` ?

Answer (score 1):

Like you say,  if you want a class that can create Rectangle. I would code something like:

```
public class Rectangle {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private static int MAX_WIDTH = 100;
    private static int MAX_HEIGHT = 100;
    private String name;

    Rectangle(int height, int width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems with your code.

First of all (and this directly has to do with your question), why did you make the variables `static`? When you make member variables `static`, then there's only one copy of the variables that is shared by all instances of the class, instead of that there is a separate copy of the variables for every instance of the class. What `static` means exactly is explained in more detail in Oracle's Java Tutorials, see the link that Turing85 mentioned in the comments.

Second, this is not a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html):

```
public static void Rectangle(){
```

Instead, it's a static method that happens to have the same name as the class. You most likely meant to implement a constructor instead:

```
public Rectangle() {
```

Third, this line:

```
String name = "default";
```

does not initialize the member variable `name`. Instead, it declares a local variable `name` that hides the member variable, and initializes the local variable (not the member variable) to `"default"`. Remove the type `String` if your intention is to initialize the member variable:

```
name = "default";
```